# Specifying an application function with clojure.spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Consider the following `apply`-like function:

```clj
(defn apply [f v]
  (f v))
```

I would like to specify this function in such a way that its return value satisfies the same specification as the return value of `f`. Furthermore I would also like to specify that the input value `v` satisfies the specification of the input of `f`.

My attempt at specifying something like this is the following:

```clj
(s/fdef apply
  :args (s/cat :f (s/fspec :args (s/cat :v any?) :ret any?))
  :ret any?)
```

This specification is very loose. What I would like to do is to quantify over two predicates `returned?` and `argument?` to further constrain the specification.

```clj
(s/fdef apply
  :args (s/cat :f (s/fspec :args (s/cat :v argument?) :ret returned?))
  :ret returned?)
```

Where `argument?` and `returned?` represent two arbitrary predicates. From what I understand this type of quantification is not possible in `clojure.spec`.

More generally, this type of behavior can be naturally expressed using any parametric type system, including Java's generics. Is this also specifiable using `clojure.spec`?

Comment: How do you add a specification for arguments and return values of `f`?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov the specification for `f` could be ideally provided using `fspec`. I updated my question to include one of my attempted specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some function to figure out the spec for the input argument `f`. I am not aware of any such function so here is one possibility. Yes, I know, it is pretty dirty:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
         '[clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest])

(defn find-fn-spec [f]
  (first
   (for [[fvar fns] (-> #'stest/instrumented-vars deref deref)
         :when (or (= f (:wrapped fns))
                   (= f (:raw fns)))]
     (#'s/reg-resolve! (symbol fvar)))))
```

Then you can use that function to write your the spec of some other function that I call `my-apply` (there is already a function `apply` in core):

```
(defn my-apply [f v]
  (f v))

(s/fdef my-apply
  :args (s/and (s/cat :f fn? :x any?)
               (fn [input]
                 (let [{:keys [f x]} input]
                   (s/conform (:args (find-fn-spec f)) [x]))))
  :ret any?
  :fn (fn [{:keys [args ret]}]
        (s/valid? (:ret (find-fn-spec (first args))) ret)))
```

But I wouldn't recommend you doing this...